# json parsing using ansible

Tags: json, ansible

> Hi, Could someone please help how to sort the below using ansible

```
"msg": [
    {
        "Desc": "jkl - txt to search-\n",
        "SCTASK": "SCTASK000001"
    },
    {
        "Desc": "xyz - txt to search-\n",
        "SCTASK": "SCTASK000002"
    },
    {
        "Desc": "def - txt to search-\n",
        "SCTASK": "SCTASK000003"
    },
    {
        "Desc": "def - txt to search-\n",
        "SCTASK": "SCTASK000004"
    },
    {
        "Desc": "abc- txt to search-\n",
        "SCTASK": "SCTASK000005"
    }
  ]
```

I need to get both sctask and description where 'abc' word present in 'Desc'. I tried to use where condition in my code block but it's not filtering.

```
- set_fact:
    SCT: "{{ jsoncontent.json | json_query(query)}}"
  vars:
    query: "result[*].{Desc: description, SCTASK: number}"

- name: debug
  debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{SCT}}"
  when: SCT is search("abc")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Q: ***"Get both `sctask` and `description` where 'abc' word present in 'Desc'."***

A: *json_query* is not needed. Simply use the filter [*selectattr*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        SCT: "{{ jsoncontent.json.result|selectattr('Desc', 'search', 'abc') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
SCT:
  - Desc: |-
      abc- txt to search-
    SCTASK: SCTASK000005
```

---

**Notes**

- If you want to select the items in the loop simply iterate the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ jsoncontent.json.result }}"
      when: item.Desc is search("abc")
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'Desc': 'jkl - txt to search-\n', 'SCTASK': 'SCTASK000001'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'Desc': 'xyz - txt to search-\n', 'SCTASK': 'SCTASK000002'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'Desc': 'def - txt to search-\n', 'SCTASK': 'SCTASK000003'}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'Desc': 'def - txt to search-\n', 'SCTASK': 'SCTASK000004'}) 
ok: [localhost] => (item={'Desc': 'abc- txt to search-\n', 'SCTASK': 'SCTASK000005'}) => 
  msg:
    Desc: |-
      abc- txt to search-
    SCTASK: SCTASK000005
```

- You can also create the list *SCT* in a loop. The task below gives the same result.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        SCT: "{{ SCT|d([]) + [item] }}"
      loop: "{{ jsoncontent.json.result }}"
      when: item.Desc is search("abc")
```

Comment: Can we pass the variable too to selecattr ? I tried the following but seems its picking only one variable. code contain abc and xyz                                                                                                                       - name: set variable
  set_fact:
    SCT "{{ jsoncontent.json.result | selectattr('Desc', 'contains', item.d ) }}"  
  with_items: "{{code}}"

Comment: Sure. What's preventing you from trying?